# How to add digital signature to emails using python script

Tags: python, digital-signature, x509certificate

I have a python script which use to send emails. I want to add digital signature for sending email for authentication. how a I do that using python script. I have to use only python standard libraries, can't use third party libraries. And I have to use certificate file for signing.

I have use hashlib and hmac libraries generate digital signature. when sending the sign mail outlook not take it as sign email just take as normal email

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show us your code, and explain what sort of signing you are trying to implement. If you want to use s/mime, it is unlikely you will be successful without using some third party cryptographic libraries.